# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException error on Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

i want to get a data on Internet use Retrofit Library
my code look like this :

```
@GET("?key={key}&q={quotes}")
Call<List<Pixabay.hits>> getTheData(@Query("key") String key, @Query("quotes") String quotes);
```

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`: URL query string `key={key}&q={quotes}` must not have replace block. For dynamic query parameters use `@Query`.
        for method `api.getTheData`

I get that problem, how to solve this? thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you don't have to write query parameters in your path.
`@Query` will do that for you.

replace

```
@GET("?key={key}&q={quotes}")
```

with

```
@GET("/")
```

Precisely, `{something}` parameter can be used only in path variable.
For example,

```
@GET("/key/{key}")
```

In this case, you can use `@Path` annotation instead of `@Query`.

Answer (score 0):

If you specify @GET("key?a=5"), then any @Query("b") must be appended using &, producing something like key?a=5&b=7.

If you specify @GET("key"), then the first @Query must be appended using ?, producing something like key?b=7.

So in your case no need to implement here like ?key={key}&q={quotes} just add
your domain @GET("your_domain/")

Comment: [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361)

Comment: @GET("/")
Call<List<Pixabay.hits>> getTheData(@Query("key") String key, @Query("quotes") String quotes);